# $f$ takes value $X$ at most a set of measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

When we say a real-valued function $f$ takes on $\infty$ on at most a set of measure zero, what is the precise mathematical statement of this?

I am just not familiar with the expression a function takes a value $X$ "at most a set of measure zero".

Comment: Do you know what the measure of a set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that a measurable set $B\subseteq\mathbb R$ exists with: $$\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)=\infty\}\subseteq B\text{ and }\mu(B)=0$$where $\mu$ denotes the measure that is involved.

---

Actually if you are talking about a "real-valued" function $f$ then $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)=\infty\}$ is by definition the empty set.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is actually an extended real function, so the range covers both the positive and negative infinity. I am learning this in the context of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I suspected that. You are very welcome.